# react-native javascript eslint parsing error: unexpected token

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint

I'm trying to work through the "react native made easy" tutorial and I'm running into a problem.  I'm running eslint and I'm getting a parsing error "unexpected token".  My code is exactly what the tutorial provides.  I'm not sure what is wrong with the syntax.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './TextArea.component.style';

class TextArea extends Component {
    state = {
        text : ''
    }
    render() {
        const {...extraProps} = this.props;
        return (
            <TextInput
                {...extraProps}
                style={[styles.textArea, extraProps.style]}
                multiline = {true}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                value={this.state.text}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default TextArea;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
7:11  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

Here is my .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "parserOptions": {
          "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 4],
        "semi": [2, "always"],
        "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "TextInput|PropTypes"}],
        "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 2,
        "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 2,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
        "no-undef": 2,
        "react/prop-types": 2,
        "react/jsx-no-bind": 2,
        "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replaceing `state  = ...` with a constructor where `this.state = ...`

Comment: I enclosed the state statement inside of constructor() {this.state = ...}.    That eliminated that error and brought up another: "Parsing error: Unexpected token .." on line 13, which is this line: "const {...extraProps} = this.props;".  Also now when I try to execute my code I get "missing super() call in constructor" (it was working before).  So the syntax problem is gone, but the code doesn't run.  And I still have another parsing error anyway.  I'm thinking maybe there is a problem with how eslint is configured for react-native?

Comment: reading further in the tutorial I found information talking about the ES7 feature of using class properties instead of constructors,  "By using this feature, you can define class members ( state for eg.) without the need of
constructor"  Then there is a code snippet like mine above compared to one with a constructor function.  So I added into my eslint config file: "parserOptions": {"ecmaVersion": 7,    but that didn't change the eslint output at all.  :(